# I just want my Goggle Sheets loop to stop when a specific cell = Total

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose, do-while, macro-recorder

I am currently using Google Sheets to run a USFL Fantasy football league and this is driving me insane. Basically I have a `IMPORTXML` for a website I get my stats, but the stats all come in vertical, so I made this code above to `TRANSPOSE` each individual player in a row. Currently, I have to run my code for each player but I want it to be automated to stop when the word `"Total"` is in the top cell, because I don't need the total stats in my rows. I really am not understanding why when I set `WHILE` to the `"cc_total"` variable to "!=" (not equal) "Total", it keeps running when the cell `DOES == "Total"`. What am I not getting here?

```js
function TRANSPOSE1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  do {
    spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(D18:D31),FALSE)');
    var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    spreadsheet.getRange('F5').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('F2:S2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getRange('F5:S5').insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    spreadsheet.getRange('D18:D31').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('D18:D31').deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    spreadsheet.getRange('F3').activate();
    var cc_total = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()
    cc_total.activate();
  } while (cc_total != "Total");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Currently cc_total is getting a range not a value

So your loop is not working the way you think it is

Replace `var cc_total = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()` with `var cc_total = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDisplayValue()` and replace `cc_total.activate();` with `spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate()`

Comment: That’s it! I had a feeling I was missing something I just had no idea what it was but the getDisplayValue is definitely what I was looking for. Was it always like that? Didn’t it use to be just getValue?

Comment: There is no history of any edits to your question so it is still as you wrote it.